# How can i get specific value from my ajax response

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am trying to make a PHP profile edit form where user can upload their picture as their profile picture so I use [this](https://github.com/rupomkhondaker/Bootstrap-image-upload-form)

my ajax response contain message about the information about the upload form. now my question is how can i save the image upload path to database.

or I have another form on the same page where I have a hidden field where I try to get the path of upload image from the `data` response message.

I try

```
  $('#message').change(function() {
      var filepath = $('div#message>div.alert>p>a.filepath').attr('href');
      $('input#profile_img').val(filepath);
   });
```

my hidden field of another form in same page which can same all information to database.

```
<input id="profile_img" type="hidden" name="profile_img" value="">
```

Picture upload HTML:

```
<form id="upload-image-form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div id="image-preview-div" style="display: none">
    <label for="exampleInputFile">Selected image:</label>
    <br>
    <img id="preview-img" src="noimage">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" required>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" id="upload-button" type="submit" disabled>Upload image</button>
</form>

<br>
<div class="alert alert-info" id="loading" style="display: none;" role="alert">
  Uploading image...
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="45" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 100%">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="message"></div>
```

Image upload handler

```
<?php
if ( isset($_FILES["file"]["type"]) )
{
  $max_size = 500 * 1024; // 500 KB
  $destination_directory = "uploads/profile-pic/";
  $validextensions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png");
  $temporary = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
  $file_extension = end($temporary);
  // We need to check for image format and size again, because client-side code can be altered
  if ( (($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png") ||
        ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg") ||
        ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
       ) && in_array($file_extension, $validextensions))
  {
    if ( $_FILES["file"]["size"] < ($max_size) )
    {
      if ( $_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0 )
      {
        echo "<div class=\"alert alert-danger\" role=\"alert\">Error: <strong>" . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "</strong></div>";
      }
      else
      {
        if ( file_exists($destination_directory . $_FILES["file"]["name"]) )
        {
          echo "<div class=\"alert alert-danger\" role=\"alert\">Error: File <strong>" . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "</strong> already exists.</div>";
        }
        else
        {
          $sourcePath = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
          $targetPath = $destination_directory . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
          move_uploaded_file($sourcePath, $targetPath);
          echo "<div class=\"alert alert-success\" role=\"alert\">";
          echo "<p>Image uploaded successful</p>";
          echo "<p>File Name: <a class='filepath' href=\"". $targetPath . "\"><strong>" . $targetPath . "</strong></a></p>";
          echo "<p>Type: <strong>" . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "</strong></p>";
          echo "<p>Size: <strong>" . round($_FILES["file"]["size"]/1024, 2) . " kB</strong></p>";
          //echo "<p>Temp file: <strong>" . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "</strong></p>";
          echo "</div>";
        }
      }
    }
    else
    {
      echo "<div class=\"alert alert-danger\" role=\"alert\">The size of image you are attempting to upload is " . round($_FILES["file"]["size"]/1024, 2) . " KB, maximum size allowed is " . round($max_size/1024, 2) . " KB</div>";
    }
  }
  else
  {
    echo "<div class=\"alert alert-danger\" role=\"alert\">Unvalid image format. Allowed formats: JPG, JPEG, PNG.</div>";
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Is that profile picture functionality is in two parts like first user upload picture and you show the uploaded picture by ajax response and then user click on submit button to save it in db?

Comment: @piyush yes profile pic upload is optional but I solve this by change my success function

Comment: @can you help me with multiple file upload ? and save all path to comma separated on db?

Answer (score 0):

I have change the success section like and it works

```
success: function(data){
        $('#loading').hide();
        $('#message').html(data);
        var filepath = $('div#message>div.alert>p>a.filepath').attr('href');
        $("input#profile_img").val(filepath);
    }
```